# Error when submiting form:Data truncation: Incorrect datetime

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I got this exception when I valid my form,

```
dao.DAOException: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '\xAC\xED\x00\x05sr\x00\x1Acom.sun.jmx.snmp.Timestamp\xFC\xA2\x9Fq\xB8z\xE9!\x02\x00\x04J\x00\x06crtimeJ\x00\x09sysUpTimeL\x00\x0' for column 'date' at row 1
at dao.CommandeDaoImpl.creer(CommandeDaoImpl.java:55)
at forms.InscriptionCommandeForm.inscrireCommande(InscriptionCommandeForm.java:95)
at servlets.Commande.doPost(Commande.java:50)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
```

codes part of concerned class CommandeDaoImpl:

```
public void creer(CommandeBean commande) throws DAOException {
    Connection connexion = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    ResultSet valeurAutoGenerees = null;
    try{
        connexion = daoFactory.getConnection();
        preparedStatement = DAOUtilitaire.initialisationRequetePreparee(
                connexion, SQL_INSERT, true, commande.getClient().getId(),
                new Timestamp( commande.getDate().getMillis()),
                commande.getMontant(), commande.getModePaiement(), commande.getStatutPaiement(),
                commande.getModeLivraison(), commande.getStatutLivraison());

        int statut = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        if(statut == 0){
            throw new DAOException("Echec de la creation de la commande, aucune ligne ajoutée dans la table.");
        }
        valeurAutoGenerees = preparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys();
        if(valeurAutoGenerees.next()){
            commande.setId( valeurAutoGenerees.getLong(1));
        }else{
            throw new DAOException("Échec de la création de la commande en base,"
                    + " aucun ID auto-généré retourné.");
        }
    }catch(SQLException e){
        throw new DAOException(e);
    }finally{
        DAOUtilitaire.fermeturesSilencieuses(valeurAutoGenerees, preparedStatement, connexion);
    }
}
```

Note: this two ligne concern two class of two differents projects:
at forms.InscriptionCommandeForm.inscrireCommande(InscriptionCommandeForm.java:95)
at servlets.Commande.doPost(Commande.java:50)

Edited:

```
    SQL_INSERT = "INSERT INTO commande (
id_client, 
date, 
montant, 
mode_paiement, 
statut_paiement, 
mode_livraison, 
statut_livraison) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

---

```
       CREATE TABLE tp_sdzee.Commande (
    id INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_client INT( 11 ),
    date DATETIME NOT NULL,
    montant DEC( 11 ) NOT NULL,
    mode_paiement VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL,
    statut_paiement VARCHAR( 20 ),
    mode_livraison VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL,
    statut_livraison VARCHAR( 20 ),
    PRIMARY KEY ( id ),
    CONSTRAINT fk_id_client FOREIGN KEY (id_client) REFERENCES Client(id) ON DELETE SET NULL ) 
ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Comment: what is the type of dateTime in mysql ?

Comment: the type is datetime, and I'm using jodaTime jar in my project

Comment: can you post your table structure and insert query ?

Comment: first check the library which is used for `timestamp`. It should be `java.sql.Timestamp`. Because there is `com.sun.jmx.snmp.Timestamp` in error. So it might referring wrong library.

Comment: YES MAN that solve it Thanks, how can I mark you best Answer???

Comment: but there's no arrow, can you add the same comment in the other 'section' (I mean not under my post) to vote up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey you should must check your **TIMESTAMP**

```
java.sql.Timestamp
```

They error is following line:(they date value is too wrong).

```
com.sun.jmx.snmp.Timestamp .
```

[following link as to click](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html)